# Azure AD - No application roles claims in id_token in /authorize login but there are in /token login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an application in Azure AD where I would like to login in. I try to go into such address (with /authorize at the end):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?{clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}&response_mode=fragment&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&nonce=dummy&state=12345
```

But after login i get no application roles in the it_token.

Strangely enough when I run almost the same address by from code (with /token at the end):

```
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "username", email },
            { "password", password },
            { "grant_type", "password" },
            { "scope", "openid" },
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "client_secret", secret }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
```

It returns application roles in id_token:

[image]

What is going on? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried both `/authorize` and `/token` endpoints, the id token always contains

```
"roles": [
    "Writer"
  ],
```

Here is the id token info I got from `/authorize` endpoint:

[image]

Please make sure you used the same user to login. Here are the main steps.

1.add the role in manifest.

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Writer",
      "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Writers Have the ability to create tasks.",
      "value": "Writer"
    }
  ]
```

2.[assign the user to roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles)

[image]